# Repetitive grabbing with awk

Tags: awk, match, multiple-columns

I am trying to compare two files and combine different columns of each. The example files are:

```
1.txt
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   -
chr3 22 33 . . +  chr4  60  61  XXX9  -


2.txt
chr1    11  1   X1  X2  11  12  2.443   0.843   +1  SXSD 1.3020000
chr1    11  2   X3  X4  11  12  0.888   0.833   -1  XXSD -28.887787
chr1    11  3   X5  X6  11  12  0.888   0.843   +1  XXSD 2.4909883
chr1    12  4   X7  X8  11  12  0.888   0.813   -1  CMKY 0.0009223
chr1    12  5   X9  X10 11  12  0.888   0.010   -1  XASD 0.0009223
chr1    12  6   X11 X12 11  12  0.888   0.813   -1  XUPS 0.10176998
```

I want to compare the `1st,6th` and `7th` columns of `2.txt`, with `7th`,`8th` and `9th` columns of `1.txt`, and if there is a match, I want to print the whole line of `1.txt` with `3th` and `12th` columns of `2.txt.`

The expected output is :

```
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 1 1.3020000
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 2 -28.887787
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 3 2.4909883
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 4 0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 5 0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 6 0.10176998
```

My trial is with `awk:`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1,$6,$7]=$3"\t"$12; next } { s=SUBSEP; k=$7 s $8 s $9  }k in a{ print $0,a[k] }' 2.txt 1.txt
```

It outputs only the last match and I cannot make it print all matches:

```
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 6   0.10176998
```

How can I repetitively search and print all matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended **`AWK`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ s=SUBSEP; k=$1 s $6 s $7; a[k]=(k in a? a[k]"@":"")$3"\t"$12; next }
     { s=SUBSEP; k=$7 s $8 s $9  }
     k in a{ len=split(a[k], b, "@"); for (i=1;i<=len;i++) print $0,b[i] }' 2.txt 1.txt
```

- `s=SUBSEP; k=$1 s $6 s $7` - constructing key `k` value comprised of the 1st, 6th and 7th fields of hte file `2.txt`
- `a[k]=(k in a? a[k]"@":"")$3"\t"$12` - concatenate the `$3"\t"$12` sequences with custom separator `@` within the same group (group presented by `k`)
- `s=SUBSEP; k=$7 s $8 s $9` - constructing key `k` value comprised of the 7th, 8th and 9th fields of the file `1.txt`
- `len=split(a[k], b, "@");` - split previously accumulated sequences into array `b` by separator `@`

---

The output:

```
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 1   1.3020000
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 2   -28.887787
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 3   2.4909883
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 4   0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 5   0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 6   0.10176998
```

Comment: Thank you, it was your help all the way! Can you please explain it a bit please?

Answer (score 2):

You're making it much harder than it has to be by reading the 2nd file first.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[$7,$8,$9] = $0; next }
($1,$6,$7) in a { print a[$1,$6,$7], $3, $12 }

$ awk -f tst.awk 1.txt 2.txt
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 1 1.3020000
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 2 -28.887787
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 3 2.4909883
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 4 0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 5 0.0009223
chr8 12 24 . . +  chr1  11  12  XX4   - 6 0.10176998
```

Comment: WOW! That is an awesome way. Thank you

Comment: Noted! Thank you